Resize QPixmap in size-fixed QLabel
In my GUI there is a embeded QLabel with "fixed" Size. At least Size is fixed, if user would like to zoom in/out.
So there are many very usefull attempts with QLabels resizing due to the Pixmap. But I would like to keep my QLabel-Size fixed all the time! First view of the pic should be scaled to the Labelsize:
myPixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(filepath)
myScaledPixmap = myPixmap.scaled(self.ui.LBL_bild.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

On "Mouse over Label" - Event AND "Mouse-Wheel-turned" - Event the Picture should resize, without stretching the Label. Here is my attempt:
        if self.mouse_over_pic:
        self.ui.LBL_bild.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        px = self.ui.LBL_bild.pixmap()
        lbl_size = self.ui.LBL_bild.size()
        if px:
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                faktor = 1.1
            else:
                faktor = 0.9
            new_width = int(px.width() * faktor)
            old_ratio = px.width()/px.height()
            new_height = int(new_width/old_ratio)

            scaledPix = px.scaled(new_width, new_height, transformMode=Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            self.ui.LBL_bild.setPixmap(scaledPix)

I'm facing two issues:

the Picture is getting really clumpsy during zooming... I guessed the SmoothTransformationMode should prevent it? So how can I keep the quality (solution/density) of the picture?

The Label is resizing with the pixmap. I have no clue how to prevent that. Even though I fixed the horizontal and vertical SizePolicy to Fixed, the Size is changed. I also tried painting instead of seting again:
 painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.ui.LBL_bild)
 point = QtCore.QPoint(0, 0)
 point.setX(int((lbl_size.width() - scaledPix.width())/2))
 point.setY(int((lbl_size.height() - scaledPix.height()) / 2))
 print(point.x(), " ", point.y())
 painter.drawPixmap(point, scaledPix)



But with that I didn't get any change to the picture.
I am really looking forward to your ideas.


that approach is wrong, as you're fundamentally overwriting the same pixmap every time it's scaled: imagine that every time you are zooming in or out it's like having an image file, you open it in an editor and zoom it, then save it again overwriting the same file and close the editor; proper zooming should always keep a copy of the source image. 2. that code only translates the pixmap, there's absolutely no scaling involved: use the QPainter.drawPixmap() functions that use the target and source QRect arguments. Note that, for what you need, there's no point in using QLabel.


Thanks for your comment, @musicamante. I switched over to QGraphicsView now. Found a really good post here link

Whenever you need to deal with image processing (zoom, translation, etc.) the Graphics View framework is almost always the preferred choice. It may be a bit difficult to deal with if you're not familiar with it, but it's usually much preferable (due to its modularity and relative coordinate/transform system) to the common QPainter/QWidget approach. Still, while it's not rocket science, it takes some time to get used to it, so I strongly suggest you to take your time to carefully study its documentation, especially for the coordinate system.
